# Removing dust from mobile's screen

Tags: cleaning, phone

Dust has gone inside my mobile screen and front camera. I don't know how it got there but I suspect that it has entered from the USB port. How can it be removed?

Answer (score 1):

I think  the safest approach is to take it to some phone repair place and have them help you with that, although that might or might not cost you a lot of money. If you would like to try it yourself, depends on which model of phone you have, you can look up information online for how to take apart and put back together a phone. 
This is a website that has lots of detailed step-by-step instruction on taking apart and fixing phones. 
https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown
 If you can find your phone on there, then you can decide if you want to take it to a repair shop or just open up your phone by yourself.

Comment: Do phone innards contain any "loose" parts that a blast of compressed air might displace? If not, the once open, a can of compressed air should get rid of the dust.